# query with a case with a subquery in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I have an oracle query. This query is a case with a subquery, but i have  a problem, when i execute the query, i have the following error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expecte`

I have a table with numbers.

```
Select * from numbers;
12345
33333
45456
24332
  .
  .
  .
```

and i have other temporal table to filter the table, then i need if a parameter in the table parameters_temp is 1 do a filter. If is 1 do the filter with a query that is a inner join between 2 tables

The query that i have is:

```
select number from numbers where 
number not in (SELECT number 
                            CASE
                            WHEN par.enable = 1
                            THEN (
                                SELECT number FROM NUMBER_FILTER mpf 
                                INNER JOIN service s ON mpf.id_prov = s.id_prov
                                WHERE s.id_service = 30 )
                            END
                            FROM parameters_temp)
```

Who can help me with my problem, or what is my error

Comment: second select statement missing from [table] before CASE

Comment: i have `FROM parameters_temp`

Answer (score 1):

I think this part is not valid.

```
SELECT number 
                        CASE
```

Something seems missing there - comma or from, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
select number from numbers where 
number not in (SELECT  CASE
                            WHEN par.enable = 1
                            THEN (
                                SELECT number FROM NUMBER_FILTER mpf 
                                INNER JOIN service s ON mpf.id_prov = s.id_prov
                                WHERE s.id_service = 30 ) 
                            END
                            FROM parameters_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

declaration of par obj is missing here

```
par.enable=1
```